# Video tag src not accepting a php extension?

Tags: php, html, video

I currently updated my system to play video files through the video tag in case of html5 supported browsers. Earlier we had a php script which used to give a mp4 video stream and used to play well. Now in case of video tag i m pointing its src to that .php file but its not able to pick up the video stream. However on giving direct link it immediately picks up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you can change your webserver (e.g. Apache) configuration, you can add non-standard extensions to PHP scripts.
Example:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .mp4
```

Comment: That won't work, unless you want people to download the actual PHP code as an `mp4`.  PHP is a scripting language, it [controls its own headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), and the default, set by `default_mimetype`, [is `text/html`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

Comment: So? You can just send any header you want

Comment: You never ever want to do this. Holy Cow, that'll mess up your configuration big-time! Just send the correct "Content-Type" from your  ONE specific script which generates the MP4 stream. `header("Content-Type", "video/mp4");` at the beginning of the script should do.

Comment: The point is, you do it from the script, not from the apache configuration.

Comment: The AddType directive is not meant to add an header (so, you should send header in PHP script anyway), but to be able to use .mp4 extension for a PHP file. Without such directive, if you rename your PHP script with .mp4 extension, it's not interpreted.